# What type of structure is this?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I am looking at some javascript code and attempting to find out what type of structure the following is:

```
new d["default"](f,l)
```

It seems to be a constructor, but it has an array. Is D an array? If so, wouldn't it have to be a function to call those arguments afterwards? Thank you.

EDIT: Changed C to D for clarification.

Comment: You should not add edit messages about such small changes.

Comment: `d['default']` is the same as `d.default`. Bracket notation can be used on all objects (arrays are objects too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine:

```
var d = {
  "default": function(a, b) {
    // do something to initialize a new object
  }
};
```

Then

```
new d["default"](f, l)
```

just accesses that function and calls it as a constructor. It's like

```
var constructor = d["default"];
new constructor(f, l);
```

The term for that "type of structure" is "object".  It's just plain ordinary object property reference semantics. Those bind pretty tightly, so generally an object property reference is fully evaluated before anything else. (Admittedly, the use with `new` can get a *little* weird, but in this case it's not.)

Comment: In your `d` variable, is the `default` actually the reserved keyword (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/default), or is this just a property named "default"

Comment: I believe it is just a property named "default".

Comment: @Rob yes that's right - I should edit the question to quote it in the object literal

Comment: @lux: Reserved words can be used as property names without problems (well, not in IE6 but who cares). `var d = {default: ...};` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @FelixKling agreed but I changed it to make it parallel with the expression in the OP